# Laravel sync manytomany error

Tags: php, laravel

I am attaching user_id, product_id with an extra field. Every thing is working fine until the extra field should be updated. When the field will be filled for second time instead of updating it will add another one to database. and it's obvious because I used attach instead of sync. But when I use sync I get an error.

this is my code:

```
$price = $request->input('price');
$product = Product::find($id);
$product->users()->attach(Auth::id(), ['price'  => $price]);
```

and this is the error I get when I use sync:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::formatRecordsList()
>   must be of the type array, integer given

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter of the `sync()` method should be an array. So correct syntax is:

```
$product->users()->sync([Auth::id() => ['price' => $price]]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 2):

Sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the pivot table
also the sync method will delete the models from table if model does not exist in array and insert new items to the pivot table.

So you need to do

```
$product->users()->sync([Auth::id() => ['price' => $price]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table.Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table.So you should pass an array as a first parameter to `sync()` function as

```
$product->users()->sync([Auth::id() => ['price' => $price]]);
```